# How to use where condition in getDescendantsAndSelf() laravel Baum plugin?

Tags: php, laravel-5, query-builder

I am using laravel Baum plugin to fetch nodes and using the following method.

```
$totalAccountsExpander = $transaction->accounts[$i]->getDescendantsAndSelf();
```

The above is i am using in my view.
Now `$transaction->accounts[$i]` is having values which are required. When i am using the above code it gives me correct values and working fine.

Now i wanted to add a where condition in the above code in my view. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can you specify what is this `$transaction` and what is returned by `getDescendantsAndSelf()`.

Comment: $transaction is collection and containing polymorphic relations with accounts and returns the following.

 [{"id":12,"location_id":2,"number":"AB22","amount":200,"p_name":"BC","options":null,"accountable_id":10,"accountable_type":"App\\Transaction","created_at":"2016-06-15 11:14:27","updated_at":"2016-06-15 11:14:27","parent_id":null,"lft":23,"rgt":24,"depth":0,"type":"default"}]

Comment: So if this is a collection you can directly use a **where** method on it and filter the results, check the doc.

Comment: What i actually want that all collections which are having accountable_id is 10. So it's giving me only row, but in my db there are multiple rows.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you use to do this and get only one row.

Comment: In the $transaction collection i am getting all the values just want to filter with getDescendantsAndSelf() method as per my condition.